# Trying to create a pause function using tkinter in python , but code crashing when restarting

Tags: python, tkinter, stack-overflow

This is my code. It's part of bigger code for creating a data subscription app. I am trying to add a pause and restart function to it. The pause function is working perfectly but whenever I am trying to restart, the GUI becomes non responsive and eventually crashes. Is calling `controller()` recursively causing a stack overflow?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import time

root = Tk()
root.title( "Your data subscription" )

mainframe = ttk.Frame( root, padding="10 10 10 50" )
mainframe.grid( column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S) )
mainframe.columnconfigure( 0, weight=1 )
mainframe.rowconfigure( 0, weight=1 )

scrollbar = Scrollbar( mainframe )
scrollbar.pack( side=RIGHT, fill=Y )

text = Text( mainframe, width=100, height=10, bg='black', fg='green', yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set )
text.place( x=0, y=0 )
text.pack( fill=BOTH, expand=1 )
text.config( font = ( 'courier', 10 , 'bold' ) )

def stoper():
        global control
        control = 0

def start():
        global control
        control = 1

button = ttk.Button(  mainframe, text='pause', command=stoper )
button.place(  x=100, y=170 )
button2 = ttk.Button( mainframe, text='start', command=start )
button2.place( x=200, y=170 )

global setfile
global control 
control = 1

def controler():
    global control
    if control == 0:
        time.sleep( 0.2 )
        controler()
    else:
        pass

def data( myfile ):
    global setfile
    setfile = myfile
    updater()

def updater():
    list=[]
    fname = open( setfile, 'r' )
    for line in fname:
        list.append( line )
    fname.close()
    printer( list )

def printer( mylist ):
    global control
    try:
        for ele in mylist:
            if control == 1:
                text.insert( "1.0", ele )
                root.update()
                time.sleep( 0.8 )
            else:
                controler()

        text.insert( "1.0", '----------------------------\n\n' )
        updater()
    except ( TclError, NameError ):
        pass

data( 'abc.txt' )
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `time.sleep()` suspends execution. You can't do that in a GUI application on the main thread as you need to continually process system events in the application mainloop. Calling this will make your application appear hung. Its not clear what you do want to do when it is inactive.

Comment: What do you expect? In `controler`, you're waiting 0.2 seconds and do that forever, since the variable `control` can't change so the GUI keeps paused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got some fundamental things wrong with your code, which probably contributes to the problem. For example, you should only ever create a single instance of `Tk`, and you shouldn't ever call sleep. Also, if you call `pack` on a widget, there's no point in also calling `place`

You also have a recursive call that will eventually crash because count will never change. Consider this code:

```
def controler():
    global control
    if control==0:
        time.sleep(0.2)
        controler()
    else :
        pass
```

You can remove the recursion and the sleep by rewriting it like this:

```
def controller()
    global control
    if control == 0:
        root.after(200, controller)
```

Comment: thanx bryan... the thing is i m less than a week old to python...let alone gui...so currently i m having a hard tym gtn a grasp of thngs...in d current code i was assuming dat button 'start' could be used to change d value of d variable control there by breakin the loop

Comment: Yes, the button can be used to change the values, but the way you coded it, the event loop is never given a chance to process events. You sleep, which freezes everything, then you immediately call a function that sleeps, which calls a function that sleeps, etc.

Comment: yes i got that, thanx , i changed that actually now...i removed that function.. this is what i m doing now..   for ele in mylist:
   if control==1:
    text.insert("1.0",ele)
    root.update()
    print(ele)
    time.sleep(0.8)
   else :
    while control==0:
     root.update()
     pass

Comment: @NilanjanMukherjee: you don't need to call `update` in that loop, and again, you don't want the sleep.